# Loading text file using json

Tags: python, json

I have already looked through multiple forums, and still can't find the answer to my question.

This is my code for writing to a file using json, which works:

```
def saveMember():
    import json
    with open("Members.txt", "w") as save:
        json.dump(memberList, save)
```

I can't figure out how to load this data back into my program. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of `json` ?

Comment: What's wrong with `json.load`? BTW, please don't bury your `import` statements inside function definitions, put them at the top of the file, where they belong.

Comment: What is `memberList`?

Comment: I'm a newbie.  So, I don't even know what to search for in json documentation specifically regarding my question.

Comment: should I put in my whole code?

Comment: No, we generally don't need (or want) your whole code on SO, we want a [mcve] that focuses on the specific issue you're having trouble with.

Comment: But in this case, you really should take a look at the `json` module docs, specifically the docs for `json.load` and `json.loads`.

Comment: ok. I'll take a look. thanks

Comment: Why are you saving the json produced by `dump()` in a text file instead of a `.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
    print (obj)
```

You should get the Python object which you put in json.dump

In your case, obj would be `memberList`